# How to pass user query to Next.js api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, next.js

I'm using the Listen Notes [podcast-api](https://github.com/ListenNotes/podcast-api-js) in Next.js api routes. I want the user query from my front-end form to interact with the Next.js api. So when a user inputs "history", it will send that to the api to look for podcasts that are about that topic.
I tried adding params to axios request but that doesn't seem to work.

Front-end:

```
export default function SearchBar() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
  const fetcher = async (url) => await axios.get(url, { params: {q: query } }).then((res) => res.data);
  const { data, error } = useSWR(address, fetcher);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    setAddress(`/api/podcast`);
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Input
          onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
        />
        <SearchButton type="submit">Search</SearchButton>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Api code:

```
const { Client } = require("podcast-api");

export default function handler(req, res) {
  const client = Client({
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY || null,
  });

  //"q" below should contain the user query from front-end
  client     
    .search({ q: req.params })
    .then((response) => {
      res.status(200).json(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("apiError: " + error);
    });
}
```

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the api route, it should be:

```
.search({ q: req.query.q })
```

req.params is something else on server side and that's why it wasn't coming through.

Answer (score 0):

Check if API on you NextJs app, is receiving correctly the environment variable **process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY**. Use **console.log** to test.

Reference :
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

Another check is the API path, cause NextJs use your own method to path this, you know ?!

Reference :
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

Hope this tips help you ;)

Comment: The api key is showing up correctly in the console. This also shows up in the console: "API resolved without sending a response for /api/podcast?q=test, this may result in stalled requests." This implies that it recognizes the the req.params I think?

Comment: Is the calling method right ?  Try to debug any error on API using try/catch on "res.status(200).json(response.data);", and console log this.